# Does any one have used ios-sim utility to run .app file in Simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5

How to pass `/Developer50` path to ios-sim. I am passing like this way, what is wrong in that??

```
ios-sim launch --verbose --sdk 5.0 --env /Developer50
```

this does not seems to work.

I have `/Developer`, `/Developer42` and `/Developer50` Directories with `XCode3.2`, `XCode4.0` and `XCode4.2` installed. But whenever I run this utility I am getting only iPhoneSimulator 4.0 and not 5.0. also I am showing sdkPath to `/Developer` and not `/Developer50`.

Kindly tell me what arguments should i pass to run iPhoneSimulator 5.0...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I have got my answer from the below link.

http://blog.abrahambarrera.me/2010/12/iphonesim.html

Thanks to Abraham Barrera.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, but the blog.abrambarrera.me link in the (currently) accepted answer was only a simple page to https://github.com/continuum/iphonesim according to archive.org.

The current (as of 2013/11/12 ) working phone sim launcher is:

https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim