# ios-sim: How to access command line arguments in my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, command-line, ios-simulator

I am making use of the awesome ios-sim found on [**github**](https://github.com/Fingertips/ios-sim).

It allows you to run the simulator via the command line and it also allows you to select which simulator (iphone or iPad) to use.

I am able to run my application flawlessly with it. However, I am unsure how to use the arguments passed to my application via the command line.

Has anyone done this or knows how to do this?

```
./ios-sim launch iTest.app --family ipad --args argument1 argument2
```

How do I access argument1 and argument2 in the iPhone application?

Comment: For reference go through my answer in previous link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8009472/does-any-one-have-used-ios-sim-utility-to-run-app-file-in-simulator For your reference there are many **Versions** utilities are there... each having some uniqueness..... 1. [iPhoneSim](https://github.com/jhaynie/iphonesim) 2. [iPhoneSim](https://github.com/landonf/iphonesim) 3. [WaxSim](https://github.com/square/WaxSim) if you wont found solution.. then please make clear what exactly do you want???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the main.m File you can print the arguments with:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
          NSLog(@"%s", argv[i]);
 }


@autoreleasepool {
...
...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. How can I access these argc variables in my Controller? I mean I can loop through them there but how can I store the variables so they can be accessed by the controllers later? So some sort of global variable?

Comment: try the NSUSerDefaults Class: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults and http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I am unsure where to use that! I am guessing the main.m is the only place I can access the arguments, but I can't declare NSUserDefaults in main.m?

Comment: Thank you for your continued help - this is new to me. I think I understand everything but I can't use `[standardDefaults valueForKey:1]` in my controller as `standardDefaults` isn't declared?

Comment: NSUserDefaults *standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *yourValue = [standardDefaults valueForKey:@"1"] ; NSLog(@"%@", yourValue);

Comment: Ahh! So the NSUSerDefaults is available everywhere. Awesome, it worked! Thank you very much Carl! :)

Comment: NSUserDefault is like a "Global Storage Enviroment".

Comment: @meccan your gist is not available anymore. dropping `[standardDefaults valueForKey:@"1"]` in my AppDelegate.m is not working, I get `null`. Is there anything else to do (like create a main.m that would set the standardDefaults?)

Comment: @Olivier you shoudl use [standardDefaults objectForKey:@"1"]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get the arguments:

```
[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] arguments];
```

I know this is an old question, but I thought I'd post it for future reference.

Answer (score -2):

iOS doesn't support command-line access.
This is from Apple's Cocoa Fundamentals Guide, Page 17
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/WhatIsCocoa/WhatIsCocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH3-SW27

> Generally, the system libraries and frameworks of iOS that ultimately
>   support UIKit are a subset of the libraries and frameworks in Mac OS
>   X. For example, there is no Carbon application environment in iOS,
>   there is no command-line access (the BSD environment in Darwin), there
>   are no printing frameworks and services, and QuickTime is absent from
>   the platform. However, because of the nature of the devices supported
>   by iOS, there are some frameworks, both public and private, that are
>   specific to iOS.