# How to start Mobile Safari from Mac command line

Tags: ios, macos, command-line, mobile-safari

I'd like to open Mobile Safari with specific url from Mac command line. I'm testing web pages and I'd like to automate testing, but I'm not able to open mobile safari on ipad connected through usb from my mac using some tool. Any suggestions?

Comment: this question was answered here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702034/ios-sim-how-to-access-command-line-arguments-in-my-iphone-application

Comment: No, it is not answered. My question is not about simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across your post, if you use a jailbroken device you could use sbopenurl to launch mobilesafari from cmd line in terminal on the device.